# not able to print object to console in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, constructor

I am new to Java and using the NetBeans IDE. I have created a MyClone class with no errors. It has a constructor method that takes no arguments. When using the constructor in my test class, I run my code with no errors but am not getting any results printed to the console. I don't know why I don't get any results.

package myclone;

```
public class MyCloneTest {

public static void main(String[]args){
    //Constructs a MyClone object
    MyClone myClone1 = new MyClone();
    //Test the setters & getters
    myClone1.setfirstName("Ryan");
    myClone1.setlastName("Geary");
    myClone1.setage(32);
    myClone1.setsex("Male");
    myClone1.setweight(168);
    myClone1.seteyeColor("brown");
    myClone1.sethairColor("brown");
    myClone1.setintro("Hello. Welcome to my fisrt Java program");
    System.out.print("First Name: " + myClone1.getfirstName() + "/n");
    System.out.print("Last Name: " + myClone1.getlastName() + "/n");
    System.out.print("Age: " + myClone1.getage() + "/n");
    System.out.print("Sex: " + myClone1.getsex() + "/n");
    System.out.print("Weight: " + myClone1.getweight() + "/n");
    System.out.print("Eyes: " + myClone1.geteyeColor() + "/n");
    System.out.print("Hair: " + myClone1.gethairColor() + "/n");
    System.out.print(myClone1.getintro() + "/n");
 } 
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing MyClone class (at least any bounded field, getter and setter) and your output

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Eclipse. 
Are you sure you really launching the main method? In Eclipse I set the cursor IN the main method and press run.
If so, then try to export your project to a runnable jar and try the jar in the (windows/linux) console itself.

```
java -jar myapplication.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the set and get methods are correctly defined in MyClone Class  .. check to see the names of methods (uppercase or lowercase characters) also post the code of MyClone Class as well here